# Cambiar de vista a una app ya desarollada Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, app, diseño, vistas, menu

Hola buenas aqui con los expertos de programacion, me han ayudado mucho esta pagina a resolver mis dudas de programacion, pero ahora si llevo 1 mes en querer resolver esto y no lo eh podido solucionar.

Tengo una app en 0cr ya desarollado el problema es de que no puedo cambiar la pantalla principal (camara) a pantalla principal en blanco para antes de entrar a la camara tener un Menu, intento con el *Android manifest(code) y el startactivity.java* (code) pero sin resultados, eh intentando arrancar la app en el cell, me marcar error. cambie la orden en android manifest no sale ya el error pero se ve todo en blanco, les agradeceria de su ayuda

Android Manifest

```
`?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.codetr.tanwir.textandlanguageusecamera">
    <!--android:installLocation="preferExternal"-->
    <!--<uses-sdk-->
    <!--android:minSdkVersion="30"-->
    <!--android:targetSdkVersion="30" />-->

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" />

    <application

        android:icon="@drawable/shutter"
        android:label= "@string/app_name">

        <activity

            android:name=".StartActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
            android:name=".CaptureActivity">

        </activity>

    </application>

    

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

</manifest>`
```

Start Activity

```
``package com.codetr.tanwir.textandlanguageusecamera;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button Escanear;
    Button Button10;




    protected void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.startactivity);

        Button10 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button10);
        Escanear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);
        Button10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //buton 1         camara   //buton 3 calculadora
                Intent Button10 = new Intent(StartActivity.this, CalculatorActivity.class);
                startActivity(Button10);
            }
        });

        Escanear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //inicio  ventana 1 a 2
                Intent Escanear = new Intent(StartActivity.this, CaptureActivity.class);
                startActivity(Escanear);
            }

        });

    }
``
```

Comment: Que error marca en el Logcat?

Comment: @Jorgesys gracias por responderme amigo cuando en el class lo cambio de public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity a nomas activity ya no me marca el error pero no se ve la pantalla bueno me marca en el logcat esto: .298 667-895/? E/nanohub: osLog: [NanoMinion] fragment_size 8 != parsed_fragment_size 19523.
Tambien esto: 599 12941-13145/? E/nightwatch-target: lmkd detector (kind 1) loop: waited 7044 ms, force_creation=no; oom_score_adj=0, rc=0; oom_adj=0, rc=0.
e igual esto:  E/bt_btm: BTM_BleObserve Observe not active

Comment: Debes buscar donde dice "Caused by", es importante usar el LogCat de otra forma algo que puedas resolver en unos minutos puede ser de dias.

Comment: Hola jorge de nuevo fijate que cuando lo pongo con el emulador no me aparece ahorita lo ando testeando con un google pixel xl (fisico) me marca el siguiente error en el log cat 2022-07-04 13:29:43.089 11971-12059/? W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bytedance.bdturing.verify.IdentityService